# How can I copy the Matrix/Transform values of a System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle and apply them to a System.Windows.Rect in a WPF canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, collision-detection, shapes

I'm trying to detect collisions between 2 Rectangles. It works, however one of the rectangles is tilted and rotated and the `Rect` that I'm creating from it doesn't have these values, it just has the Left,Top,Width and Height, how can I apply the values of a `System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle` to the `System.Windows.Rect` that I'm creating programatically? Thanks in advance :)

Here is an idea of the code that I'm using below:

```
internal static bool CheckIfCharacterCanMove(Rectangle Character, string RoomName)
    {
        if (RoomName == "PlayerRoom")
        {
            #region Collision creation
            Rect PlayerHitBox = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(Character), Canvas.GetTop(Character), Character.Width, Character.Height);

            Rect Wall1HitBox = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(PageController.PlayerRoom.Wall1), Canvas.GetTop(PageController.PlayerRoom.Wall1), PageController.PlayerRoom.Wall1.Width, PageController.PlayerRoom.Wall1.Height);
            Rect Wall2HitBox = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(PageController.PlayerRoom.Wall2), Canvas.GetTop(PageController.PlayerRoom.Wall2), PageController.PlayerRoom.Wall2.Width, PageController.PlayerRoom.Wall2.Height);
            Rect Wall3HitBox = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(PageController.PlayerRoom.Wall3), Canvas.GetTop(PageController.PlayerRoom.Wall3), PageController.PlayerRoom.Wall3.Width, PageController.PlayerRoom.Wall3.Height);
            Rect Wall4HitBox = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(PageController.PlayerRoom.Wall4), Canvas.GetTop(PageController.PlayerRoom.Wall4), PageController.PlayerRoom.Wall4.Width, PageController.PlayerRoom.Wall4.Height);
            #endregion
            #region Collision detection
            if (PlayerHitBox.IntersectsWith(Wall1HitBox))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Collision detected with Wall1");
                Canvas.SetLeft(Character, Canvas.GetLeft(PageController.PlayerRoom.Wall1) + 20);
                return false;
            }
            if (PlayerHitBox.IntersectsWith(Wall2HitBox))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Collision detected with Wall2");
                Canvas.SetTop(Character, Canvas.GetTop(PageController.PlayerRoom.Wall2) + 20);
                return false;
            }
            if (PlayerHitBox.IntersectsWith(Wall3HitBox))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Collision detected with Wall3");
                Canvas.SetLeft(Character, Canvas.GetLeft(PageController.PlayerRoom.Wall3) - 210);
                return false;
            }
            if (PlayerHitBox.IntersectsWith(Wall4HitBox))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Collision detected with Wall4");
                Canvas.SetTop(Character, Canvas.GetTop(PageController.PlayerRoom.Wall4) - 210);
                return false;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("No collision detected");
            return true; //returns true because no collision was detected so the objet can move
            #endregion
        }
        else
        {
            return true;//Just here to serve the compiler, should be ignored.
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't "*copy the values to a Rect*", because a Rect does not know anything about transformations. You have to do the math yourself. As a note, your `return true;` to "*serve the compiler*" is entirely redundant. Write it after the `if/else` block and remove the other one from the `if` branch.

Comment: @Clemens thank you for the input, I'll have a look at it!